# how to add shake animation for a span element inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <div id="about-desc">
    <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span class="animation">amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="animation"> Officia reprehenderit</span>, <span class="animation"> sit eligendi</span> deserunt, blanditiis quas porro omnis provident quidem voluptate! Fugit ipsa mollitia, atque commodi asperiores, rerum dicta ratione aut.
    </p>
 </div>

$(document).ready(function () { 
  $(".animation").addClass("animated shake");
});
```

I am not able to figure out where i actually went wrong. When i add animation to div element it is working correctly but it's not happening with span element? Can somebody explain how to solve this problem

Comment: try to add `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` on the `span` maybe?

Comment: Maybe the `span` element needs a `display: inline-block` property.

Comment: where is your CSS?

Comment: You can copy/adjust the example here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/shake-css-keyframe-animation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

span is an inline element by default and therefore can not perform a transformation. Add `display: inline-block` to your animation or add to the span so it is transformable.

> ### transformable element
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
>
> an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, patternTransform or gradientTransform [SVG11].
>
> REF: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#terminology
>
> The HTML `<span>` element is a generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything. It can be used to group elements for styling purposes (using the class or id attributes), or because they share attribute values, such as lang. It should be used only when no other semantic element is appropriate. **`<span>` is very much like a `<div>` element, but `<div>` is a block-level element whereas a `<span>` is an inline element**.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

### Option 1: Shake on hover

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $(".animation").addClass("animated shake");
});
```

```css
.shake:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="about-desc">
    <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span class="animation">amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="animation"> Officia reprehenderit</span>, <span class="animation"> sit eligendi</span> deserunt, blanditiis quas porro omnis provident quidem voluptate! Fugit ipsa mollitia, atque commodi asperiores, rerum dicta ratione aut.
    </p>
 </div>
```

### Option 2: shake forever

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $(".animation").addClass("animated shake");
});
```

```css
.shake {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="about-desc">
    <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span class="animation">amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="animation"> Officia reprehenderit</span>, <span class="animation"> sit eligendi</span> deserunt, blanditiis quas porro omnis provident quidem voluptate! Fugit ipsa mollitia, atque commodi asperiores, rerum dicta ratione aut.
    </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: @arun Cool, Welcome to stackOverflow, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you! :D